Angular 18.1 - should one use typescript functions with new @let?
Generally using functions in views in Angular is not recommended, because of change detection, and why pipes are recommended instead (they only run, when the input value changes).
But now what about with the new @let function.
When you have signals, the following is now recommended.
@let signalVar = signalVar()
@if(signalVar) { ... }

vs.
@if(signalVar(); as signalVar) {

}

Question:
But should one call things like:
@let result = complexTypeScriptFunction(signalVar()) | anotherPipe

etc.
Does this get around the 'do not use methods' in Angular templates, because of change detection  problem?

I'd say no if the function takes some compute time given this function will still run every time the view needs to get updated due to change detection. The recommended approach would be to move that expensive computation to the definition of signalVar, to ensure that it's only performed when the signal value is updated

In Angular 18.2 it's better to use pipes instead of functions to assign the results to a template variable. I have checked and even with an OnPush change detection strategy, the function gets called multiple times not changing its arguments, or anything in the component, just triggering some events with mouse clicks.
A pipe, on the other hand, will only be called when it's arguments have changed.
I'm not sure at all how this will evolve. It probably will be improved in next Angular releases 

lets hope so. Pipes are annoying
